# How to validate users input before action

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm really new in internet languages and i try to figure out how it's possible to validate the users input before method call but i just can't make it work yet.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php
        $grade = "";
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
        {
            $returned = test_input($_POST["grade"]);
            if(!$returned) ?
        }

        function test_input($data) 
        {
            if ( !is_numeric($data) || $data>100 || $data<0 )  
            {
                $data = "";
                echo 'The input should be a number between 0 and 100 ';
                echo "<br>";
                echo 'Try again';
                return false;
            }       
            return true;
        }
        ?>

        <form action = "file_1_2.php" method = "post">
        Grade: <input type="text" name="grade">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably change this `$data>0` to this `$data<0` (less than zero). And also this `<form action = "file_1_2.php" method = <"post">` to this `<form action = "file_1_2.php" method = "post">` (drop the errant `<` character).

Comment: What type of validation do you want to do?

Comment: You can use jquery for validation. It's very easy

Comment: if ( !is_numeric($data) || $data>100 || $data<0 ) this is actually the validation i want to do before sending the data to the next php file. beercodebeer thnx for the info.

Comment: Chris G i would like to learn more things about php html before trying something else but thnx for the hint.

Comment: You should not rely on client-side validation anyway. The user can turn it off, then you have no validation. You are best to stick with server-side validation, then add client-side, time permitting.

Comment: Also, have your function just return a `bool` value, don't make it echo anything. That way you can reuse the function later without it returning an error value that you can't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my and other comments, your function has incorrect `if` clauses, specifically your greater than, less than. I would suggest not echoing any strings from it otherwise you have a limited-use function.

```
function input_valid($data = false)
    {
        if(empty($data))
            return false;
        elseif($data && !is_numeric($data))
            return false;
        else
            return (($data <= 100) && ($data > 0));
    }

if(isset($_POST["grade"])) {
    if(input_valid($_POST["grade"])) {
        // Do stuff.
    }
    else {
        echo 'Invalid input. Must be a number between 1 and 100.';
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I feel it's important to re-iterate my comment above which is *you SHOULD NOT rely solely on client-side validation. The user can turn it off, then you have no validation. Client-side validation should be considered only as a "user experience" feature, not a "security" feature.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try using jquery

```
    <form action = "file_1_2.php" method = "post">
    Grade: <input type="text" name="grade" class="grade" onkeyup="">
    </form>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function(){
             $('input.grade').bind("keyup change", function(){

                validateGrade( $(this).val() );

             });
        });

        function validateGrade(g){
            if(g>100 || g<0){
                alert('The input should be a number between 0 and 100');
            }
        }
    </script>
```